# Error when trying to deploy spfx package to Apps catalog From SharePoint Store

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an SPFX App in AppSource that is working perfectly on existing deployment. The App was approved by the validation team on May this year. So, the App is quite newly updated.

I am working on a new deployment for a new customer. However, I am not able to deploy the App from the Store? The user I am using is primary admin on the App catalog site and is Global admin on the tenant.

I have tried deploying from the Store and also uploading directly but I keep running into the same issue. The deployment seems to be ok. However, the status keeps being “Disabled”, that even if I try to enable the App.

Question is if this is a general error or has there been made updates since May that we need to make to the spfx package?